# There has got to be a better way to write this

Tags: java

```
public static boolean isValidCoordinate(Coordinate point) {
    Point map = point.mapCoordinates, tileSet = point.tileSetCoordinates, tile = point.tileCoordinates, pixel = point.pixelCoordinates;
    if (map != null && map.x >= 0 && map.y >= 0) {
        if (tileSet != null) {
            if (tileSet.x >= 0 && tileSet.y >= 0) {
                if (tile != null) {
                    if (tile.x >= 0 && tile.y >= 0) {
                        if (pixel != null) {
                            if (pixel.x >= 0 && pixel.y >= 0) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The coordinate class holds 4 Point objects, representing a unique set of coordinates. Each set of coordinates needs to be positive. mapCoordinates cannot be null, but the other Points can, as long as everything after them is null, and everything before them is positive in this list: mapCoordinates, tileSetCoordinates, tileCoordiantes, pixelCoordinates. Thanks

Comment: Really seriously ambigous question name.

Comment: srsly put these if and else branches into a single logical equation.

Comment: If you open this code in IntelliJ and press Alt+Enter enough times, it will simplify this for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course there is. Use methods to keep DRY:

```
boolean isValid(Point p) {
    return p == null || (p.x >= 0 && p.y >= 0);
}

boolean isValid(Coordinate c) {
    return isValid(c.mapCoordinates)
        && isValid(c.tileSetCoordinates) 
        && isValid(c.tileCoordinates) 
        && isValid(c.pixelCoordinates);
}
```

And yes, calling the variables of type `Point` `coordinate` and those of type `Coordinate` `point` is likely to confuse the reader.

Comment: +1: Making a Coordinate `c` is clearer, but you have to change all the uses. i.e. `s/point/c/` ;)

Comment: Argh, I missed the return true among all those return false ... fixed.

Comment: Still not equivalent as map can't be true. Still a +1 though.